# «Много луж» — это словосочетание?

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания, подчинительная-связь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **много луж** — это словосочетание?
Если да, то к какому типу связи относится? Управление?

Answer (score 1):

Первое. Конечно же, "много луж" — это [**словосочетание**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/chto-takoe-slovosochetanie.html).

Словосочетание — это синтаксическая единица, состоящая из двух и более слов и строящаяся на основе подчинительной связи.
***Много*** (чего?) **луж** — словосочетание состоит из главного и зависимого слова. Главным является то слово, от которого ставится вопрос к зависимому.

Второе. Вид связи в словосочетании — **управление**, то есть главное слово требует постановки зависимого только в определенном падеже (у нас — в родительном).

[МНОГО](http://endic.ru/academic/Mnogo-20834.html), *наречие*
**1.** *в значении числительного*
Неопределенно большое количество **кого-либо, чего-либо.**
Много раз; нас много; много работы; много солнца; много дел.

Третье. "Много луж" — это [**неделимое словосочетание**](https://fb.ru/article/392258/nedelimyie-slovosochetaniya-eto-chto-takoe).

Синтаксически неделимое словосочетание в предложении — это такая конструкция, которую нельзя разъединить без потери смысла (она является отдельным членом предложения).
*Из-за воскресного дождя в городе образовалось* (что?) ***много луж.***

Answer (score 0):

Данный вид словосочетания называется управлением. Главное слово управляет падежной формой зависимого слова.

*Много* (чего?) *цветов*.